# Is there a faster way to validate uncorrupted JSON than fully parsing it?

Tags: json, shell, validation, logging, optimization

I have a process that logs newline-delimited JSON at large rates (50-100 MB/s) across several instances which is logrotated out and gzipped. Those logs then run through a validation step that ensures that the file is valid for my ETL workflow by doing basic checks on things like gzip truncation. The problem is that due to some yet-unresolved issue, that gzip file, in rare cases, contains corrupted/interrupted JSON blobs, for example:

```
{
 "firstAttribute": "foo1", 
 "secondAttribute": "bar1", 
 "thirdAttribute": "ba{"firstAttribute": "foo2", 
    "secondAttribute": "bar2", 
    "thirdAttribute": "baz2"}
```

When these corrupted values hit the ETL flow, it brings the whole thing to a halt until I can identify exactly which of the thousands of files is causing the problem.

So far, the fastest way I've found to detect this corrupted JSON is by using `jq`:

```
zcat $file | if jq -e . > /dev/null 2>&1; then mv "$file" /good/; else mv "$file" /bad/; fi; done
```

Unfortunately, due to the size of the files, this check adds 1-2 seconds per file; at that rate, new files are created more quickly than they can be validated.

I'm looking for a solution that does a JSON corruption check as quickly as possible; false positives are ok and can be dealt with using the slower check, but any false negatives mean that I may as well not have checked at all. All possible solutions are welcome, any language, as long as they can be run on a Linux instance. Otherwise, I'm going to need to figure out running checks in parallel which may involve more CPU than the system generating the logs in the first place.

**EDITED TO ADD**
There was a suggestion to try using simd as an alternative parsing engine. I tried a very basic prototype, below, but it actually added 1-2s per file over the `jq` method.

```
#include "simdjson.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace simdjson;
int main(void) {
  ondemand::parser parser;
  for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
    padded_string json = padded_string(line);
    ondemand::document doc = parser.iterate(json);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Json library used, the actual text parsing can be the most expensive part of decoding a Json document, but not always. Creating/Allocating Json object can be quite expensive too. String decoding is especially costly due to UTF-8. Only checking a Json document can be a bit faster, but for most library/tools, the parsing is not well optimized and would be rather slow even without the other overheads. [SimdJson](https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson) is a very fast implementation using SIMD instruction to parse Json document much faster than a lot of library (generally between 100 MB/s and 1 GB/s). It should check errors correctly and can perform a fast lazy document evaluation. It is available in C++ and Python (although the Python package is slower mainly because of the expensive Python object construction).

However, one main issue in your case is the decompression of gzipped files. Gzip is a pretty slow format to compress/decompress and poorly suited for modern computers : the decompression of a gzipped stream cannot be efficiently done with multiple core nor using SIMD instruction. Much faster compression/decompression methods exists for new emerging formats like LZ4 or Zstd. If you cannot change the input format, then you will likely be bound by the decompression speed. If there is multiple files, you can decompress the stream in parallel. You can use GNU parallel to do that easily.

Comment: So, I tried to use SimdJson (very basic prototype, added to question) and it added 1-2s per file over `jq`.

Comment: Reading the file line by line is probably inefficient (because of the allocation and internal copies). How long are the lines and how many lines there are? Is there always 1 full Json document per line? By the way, do not forget to enable optimization flags (like `-O3`) although it should not be much better with them.

Comment: There are somewhere around 10k records per file, each record/line is about 12k characters.

Comment: Decompression accounts for about 400ms.

Comment: Ok, so you can use parallelism to speed up the computation (assuming the records are fully independent). OpenMP can be used to easily do that (with taskloop). Note that the granularity of task should be controlled so that they are not too small. For the decompression I missed the fact that text decompression is often significantly faster.